# Unable to call api in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-services

I am trying to call the `api` using **httpClinent** method, while i log,i am getting result as **undefined**.

Below is the the **services** file code.

**contact-service.services.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Customers } from 'src/app/mymodels/app.models';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ContactServiceService {
 private baseUrl: string  = '............api URL..........';

 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getCustomers(){

   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).subscribe(data => {});

  }

}
```

**app.models.ts**

```
 export interface Customers {
  id:                     string;
  firstName:              string;
  lastName:               string;
  fullName:               string;
}
```

Component CODE

**TS**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import {
   FormBuilder,
   FormControl,
   FormGroup,
  Validators,
   } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Customers } from 'src/app/mymodels/app.models';
import { ContactServiceService } from 'src/app/Services/contact- 
    service.service';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-get-contact',
  templateUrl: './get-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./get-contact.component.css']
 })

 export class GetContactComponent implements OnInit {
  public customers : Customers [];

  constructor(public customersService: ContactServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.customers = this.customersService.getCustomers();

    console.log(this.customers);  

   }

 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let customer of customers">
  <p>{{customer.firstName}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: in subscribe you are not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service code be just like,

```
getCustomers(){
   return this.http.get(this.baseUrl);
}
```

and call **`.subscribe`** in your component as follows,

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.customersService.getCustomers().subscribe((data)=> {
    this.customers = data;
    console.log(this.customers);  
});
```

Comment: Getting this error: **ERROR in src/app/get-contact/get-contact.component.ts(25,3): error TS1005: ',' expected.**

Comment: there was extra ) missing. check now